# Error al crear proyecto Grails en NetBeans

Tags: netbeans-8.2, grails

El error que tengo es el siguiente:

```
Warning |
Unrecognized flag: non-interactive.
Resolving dependencies..
Error |
Specify an application name or use --inplace to create an application in the current directory
```

Estoy siguiendo los pasos que vienen en la página de [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/grails-quickstart.html).

Tengo instalado:

- Grails 3.3.8.
- Groovy 2.4.15.
- NetBeans 8.2.

Desde consola cree un proyecto usando `grails create-app helloworld` y en este caso parece que no hubo problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente no funciona. Yo suelo crear las apps desde linea de comandos y después utilizo netbeans.

También puedes probar lo que contestan en este hilo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424377/why-i-cant-create-new-grails-application-in-netbeans-8-2

Comment: Las respuestas que son básicamente enlaces se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor edita tu respuesta aportando lo más importante de dicho enlace por si llega a dejar de funcionar en un futuro.